# Как менять класс div по данному событию?

Tags: javascript, html5

Вот есть пример, как по событию менять класс и оставлять только один класс например `<div class="success">` а не стакать их в один класс например `<div class="success error">` (как разультат на примере)

```
<div id="formresult"></div>
<script>
if (result == 'success') {
$("#formresult").text('Выполнено успешно').addClass('success');
}
else if (result == 'error') {
$("#formresult").text('Произошла ошибка').addClass('error');
}
else if (result == 'zero') {
$("#formresult").text('Попробуйте еще').addClass('tryagain');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну как вариант, используя ваш код

```
<div id="formresult"></div>
<script>
if (result == 'success') {
$("#formresult").text('Выполнено успешно').attr('class', 'success');
}
else if (result == 'error') {
$("#formresult").text('Произошла ошибка').attr('class', 'error');
}
else if (result == 'zero') {
$("#formresult").text('Попробуйте еще').attr('class', 'tryagain');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо работает, а как каждый класс в переменной отобразить?

Comment: var succ = 'success';
if (result == 'nocreate') {
$("#formresult").text('Ошибка').attr('class', 'succ?');
}

Comment: @Антон по такой же логике - var SomeVar = $('#formresult').attr('class');

Comment: Сделал так: .attr('class', ( variable ));